# Create a daemon for a custom service on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, service, daemon

I'm trying to create a daemon for a linux service.

Actually, I can launch the service from my home directory like this:

```
cd /home/admin/myservice/build && ./myservice file.dat
```

Note that I need to add the file.dat as an "argument" else the service can't start.

Well, this is what I did.
First I created a simple script to launch the service in **/usr/bin**. The file name is myservice.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/admin/myservice/build && ./myservice file.dat
```

Then, I gave exec rights to this script:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/myservice.sh
```

Then, I create a new script in **/etc/init.d** called myservice. I used the skeleton:

```
sudo -s
cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/myservice
```

The content is:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Myservice Daemon"
NAME=myservice
DAEMON=/usr/bin/myservice.sh
DAEMON_ARGS="--options args"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
```

Then, I gave exec rights to the script:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/myservice
```

I ran this to activate the daemon:

```
update-rc.d myservice defaults
```

Now I can launch the daemon like this:

```
/etc/init.d/myservice start --quiet --background
```

But it works as before:
- it is not launched in background (I can't use the same shell session)
- each time I closed the shell it will break
- and how to make it run at system start ?

What did I miss ?

**EDIT: just added "&" at end of line:**

```
 cd /home/admin/myservice/build && ./myservice file.dat &
```

Now it works as expected.
I can restart the machine and the service runs !

Comment: I found the solution. See EDIT.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a link where you found the solution, what does the & at the end of the command means?

Comment: With the & the process starts in the background.